# Named pipe hanging on read

Tags: .net, named-pipes

I have a named pipe server.  The client sends the message, which seems OK, however the server just hangs on the line `var stringData = textReader.ReadToEnd();`.

```
var namedPipeServerStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(_pipeName,
                        PipeDirection.In,
                        1,
                        PipeTransmissionMode.Byte,
                        PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

namedPipeServerStream.WaitForConnection();

using (var textReader = new StreamReader(namedPipeServerStream))
{
    var stringData = textReader.ReadToEnd();

    _callback(stringData);

    namedPipeServerStream.Flush();
    namedPipeServerStream.Close();
}

Thread.Sleep(1);
```

The client looks like so:

```
public void Send(string message)
{
    var pipeStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(_serverName,
        _pipeName,
        PipeDirection.Out,
        PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

    pipeStream.Connect(_timeout);

    var buffer = UTF8.GetBytes(message);

    pipeStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

Why is this hanging?

Answer (score 3):

NamedPipe streams, like network streams, have no definite end, they just temporarily "dry up", that's why your `ReadToEnd` call indefinitely tries to read more data.

However, you could change the `PipeTransmissionMode` to `Message` on the server-side to make each write to the pipe to be treated as a separate message, and then read from the stream until `IsMessageComplete` returns `true`. e.g.:

```
using (var namedPipeServerStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(_pipeName,
                PipeDirection.InOut,
                1,
                PipeTransmissionMode.Message,
                PipeOptions.Asynchronous))
{
    namedPipeServerStream.WaitForConnection();

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
    do { ms.Write(buffer, 0, namedPipeServerStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)); }
    while (!namedPipeServerStream.IsMessageComplete);

    string stringData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    _callback(stringData);
}

Thread.Sleep(1);
```

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what exactly setting the `PipeTransmissionMode ` to `Message` does.  Does it add some delimitation between messages?

Comment: I also found that disposing of the `NamedPipeClientStream` prevents the server from hanging.

Comment: @BanksySan, there's no delimiter, the native operating system API sets the underlying flag for `IsMessageComplete` once all bytes related to a single write are read by the server stream.

Comment: I guess it has to be set in both the client and the server then?

Comment: @BanksySan not unless you are planning to read from the stream from the client side too, in that case, you should set `NamedPipeClientStream`'s `ReadMode` _after_ calling `Connect`.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, and I fixed it with flush on the WRITE side.

Flush pipe on client side right after stream writing so that the server side can get the message.